# Is it possible to indentify when a Contact is being created with Email-To-Salesforce and when it isn't?

Tags: visual-workflow, administration, emailtosalesforce

Hello and thanks for reading!

I have a section in the Contact layout with these fields:

Opt out of Email

Do Not Call

Do Not Contact

I've added a checkbox called Lead Only/No Auto Emails. As users manually add new Contacts, they'll be checking that to prevent them from receiving automated communication.

The idea is to set up a new flow. When a contact makes a donation for the first time, automatically uncheck that box.

We are using SFDC's BCC Email-To-Salesforce feature, often creating new contacts with it. Is it possible to know that a contact originated from one of those emails and automatically check the box?

Comment: Why not just default the field as checked? That should solve your problem. Also, one fewer clicks for your UI users.

Comment: Good thought. Thank you :)  The problem with defaulting it as checked is that there are a lot of integrations creating new contacts in this setup: donations, text messages, Facebook ads/leads, web forms, etc. I would need to update all of them to explicitly UNcheck that box.